# Hiding compass and legal in MKMapView results rejection in App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, mkmapview

I want to hide legal and compass in MKMapView.

```
self.mapView.showsCompass = NO;
[[self.mapView.subviews objectAtIndex:1] removeFromSuperview];
```

Can it result rejection in App Store??

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the compass is no problem. Hiding the legal notice will definitely get you rejected.

Comment: Thanks. But can I change "legal" buttons frame?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: I don't know. I thought I remembered seeing in the docs that you the map view's view hierarchy is private and that you shouldn't mess with it, but I can't seem to find that now. Clearly, Apple wants that legal information to be available to the user, and if your program makes it difficult or impossible to find, they're going to reject your app.